# Building OpenCV samples

Tags: android, opencv

According to following article,

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-ndk-integration-with-eclipse

I was able to successfully build and run some of OpenCV samples - ndk and jni are also working fine. But for the other projects, I got red flags saying

```
the project cannot be built until build path error resolved.
```

But I can't find what the build path error is. I looked at the configuration of build path, I don't see a problem. I note that those failed projects have all empty OpenCV-2.3.1_src folder. Can someone experienced with this help me?

UPDATE:

I think I am hasty. I removed source reference of that empty folder from build path and it's  building now.